# IIS web app 404's after few hours

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

- Web application works normally for 10 minutes to almost 24 hours, then 404's.
- By 'works normally' I mean that I just reload the default page to see if it's alive, nothing else is done with the web app.
- Changing **web.cofig's <compilation debug="true/false"** brings it back.
- Restarting IIS or Recycling App pool does not.
- It's using MVC5 + WebAPI + Entity Framework 6 + Newtonsoft.Json
- FailedReqLogFiles show either one of these reasons:

  - ManagedPipelineHandler - EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
  - IIS Web Core - MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER
- Tested on two computers, problem occurs on both:

  - windows 10, iis 10 - local pc
  - windows server 2012, iis 8 - amazon ec2 instance
- Before asking me to post my code, what does these error indicate practically?

Comment: p.s. already tried aspnet_regiis -i, no entries in <handlers>, tried to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the app pool's advanced settings -> Recycling -> Regular time interval.
Once set to 0, everything worked. (default is 1740)
Also set the idle timeout to 0 (default is 20)

Frankly, Right now it's just about 60 hours of activity, I'll keep monitoring.